# How to configure Highcharts Boost module for large datasets use in Highcharts Gantt?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, react-highcharts, highcharts-gantt

I have a dataset made with x number of series.
When I set it to 10 series it works, but if I do 100 series, it stops working.

I suspect I need to configure turboThreshold properly but I've tried in many different ways and it doesn't work.

In case you ask why am I using Boost, my dataset is actually 450 series and it takes ages to load when I add all the properties I need so I'm giving boost a try.

```
const range = [...Array(100).keys()];

const series = range.map((_, i) => ({
  type: 'line',
  zoneAxis: 'x',
  zones: [{
    value: Date.UTC(2022, 10, 20)
  }, {
    dashStyle: 'dot',
    value: Date.UTC(2022, 10, 25)
  }],
  data: [{
    y: i,
    x: Date.UTC(2022, 10, 18),
  }, {
    y: i,
    x: Date.UTC(2022, 10, 25),
  }]
}))

Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {

  yAxis: {
    uniqueNames: true,
    categories: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  },
  series: series,
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      turboThreshold: 10000,
    }
  },
});
```

Link to a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Fmcg/9071Ltz6/181/)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the boost module is not currently available for the Gantt chart.

About data structure from Highcharts docs:

> In boost mode, turbo mode is always turned on. That means all data
> points should be configured as an array of numbers (e.g. [1, 2, 3]) or
> a two dimensional array of numbers (e.g. [ [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4] ]).

---

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module

**GitHub issue:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/17415

**Feature request:** https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/37673773-gantt-boost